# PHP OnClick form

Tags: php

I have a HTML form that looks like this:

```
<form action="stock.php" method="post">

Item1 S:<input value="remove" name="remove1S" type="submit" />
Item2 M:<input value="remove" name="remove1M" type="submit" />

</form>
```

and PHP:

```
$file = fopen("stock.txt", "a+");
//when "remove1S" is clicked on
fwrite($file,"Removed one");
//when "remove1M" is clicked on
fwrite($file,"Removed two");
```

How can I do what I have said in the comments? I am certain it is using `$_POST['remove1S']` so something like

```
if (__onClick__ $_POST['remove1S'])
{fwrite($file,"Removed one");
}
```

Comment: Well, google for [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: what you have said in what comments? why a javascript file stock.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)? It's gonna check if the `$_POST['remove1S']` exists. And this key in `$_POST` will exist if you have submitted the form.

```
if (isset($_POST['remove1S']))
{
    fwrite($file,"Removed one");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To separate between actions , use  `empty()` or `isset()` to check if value of the clicked button is not empty,then it's clicked, and if you want to do this without refreshing the page , you will need `AJAX` .

```
    $file = fopen("stock.txt", "a+");

    if (!empty($_POST['remove1S']))
    {
        fwrite($file,"Removed one");
    }
    else {
        //remove1M is clicked
        fwrite($file,"Removed two");

    }
```

Or :

```
    $file = fopen("stock.txt", "a+");

    if (isset($_POST['remove1S']))
    {
        //button remove1S is clicked

        fwrite($file,"Removed one");
    }
    else {
        //remove1M is clicked
        fwrite($file,"Removed two");

    }
```

Comment: WHY -1 ? explain please

Answer (score 0):

You can change the onClick event for the buttons to include PHP code, for example:

```
<input value="remove" name="remove1S" type="submit" onClick="<?php fwrite($file,"Removed one");?>"/>
```